# How to change Year value in Excel from a date range?

Tags: excel, date, format

I need to change year according to Fiscal Year.

```
Data now.  Data should be.
1/1/2021.  1/1/2019
2/3/2021.  2/3/2019
7/1/2021.  7/1/2018
```

For range 7/1/2021-12/31/2021 year should be changed into 2018.
For range 1/1/2021-6/30/2021 year should be changed into 2019.
All unchanged data in cell format 7/2/2021.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: What do you mean with the last sentence? And is that format MDY or DMY?? hard to tell with the days under 12.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Edate to add or subtract months from a date. Combine it with IF. something along the lines of

```
=IF(A1>=DATE(2021,7,1),EDATE(A1,-36),IF(A1>=DATE(2021,1,1),EDATE(A1,-24),A1))
```

[image]

Formatting dates is not done with formulas. Select the cells and use the format of your choice.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I got to make changes with in Fiscal Year 1 July-30 June. So for the range 7/1/2021-12/31/2021 year should be 2018. And for the range 1/1/2021-6/30/2021 year should be 2019..

Comment: You already wrote that in your question. And that is what my formula does. You can see that 7/7/2021 is changed into 7/7/2018, so the year is now 2018. And 2/3/2021 is changed into 2/3/2019, so the year is now 2019.  Just as you asked. Or did you ask for something different? Then please write out what you expect as a result.

Comment: Thank you but I actually need one step solution for 15.000 cells

Comment: Look, we're here to help, in our own free time, as unpaid volunteers, but if you don't answer questions for clarification, then it's really hard to help. And please be aware that this site is not a free script writing service.